# Generating XML from a comma separated string + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am seeking ideas for my following problem - I have to generate an XML string based on the comma separated value string - using SQL Server 2017 (v14).

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @paramKey NVARCHAR(10) = 'A'
DECLARE @paramKey2 NVARCHAR(10) = 'B'
DECLARE @Results XML;

SET @SQL = N' ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
             ''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'' AS xsi,
             ''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'' as xsd)
               (SELECT CAST((SELECT 0 AS [ID],
                                    '''' as Fuid,
                                    ''ParentNode'' as ParentNode,
                                   
                    (SELECT
                        N''' +  '' + @paramKey + '' + ''' AS [PropertyBagItem/@Key]
                        ,N''xsd:int'' AS [PropertyBagItem/Value/@xsi:type]
                        ,3500 AS [PropertyBagItem/Value]
                        ,null
                        ,N''' +  '' + @paramKey2 + '' + ''' AS [PropertyBagItem/@Key]
                         ,N''xsd:int'' AS [PropertyBagItem/Value/@xsi:type]
                        , 90  AS [PropertyBagItem/Value]                        
                    FOR XML PATH (N''Inputs''), TYPE) AS Inputs,
                     N'''' as Outputs,
                    (SELECT
                        N''Param1'' AS [PropertyBagItem/@Key]
                        ,N''xsd:int'' AS [PropertyBagItem/Value/@xsi:type]
                        ,90 AS [PropertyBagItem/Value]
                        ,null
                        ,N''Param2'' AS [PropertyBagItem/@Key]
                        ,N''xsd:int'' AS [PropertyBagItem/Value/@xsi:type]
                        ,90 AS [PropertyBagItem/Value]                        
                    FOR XML PATH (N''InputsType''), TYPE) AS InputType,
                          N'''' as OutputsType,                 
                    1 as EmployeeID,
                    N''false'' as TestRun
                    FOR XML PATH(N''TestXMLString''), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
             ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS N''XML'')'


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I have to find a way to generate the "Input" and "InputType" within the XML based on a comma separated string. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you using "dynamic" SQL here? There's no need for it to be. `N'SELECT N''' +  '' + @paramKey + '' + ''' AS [PropertyBagItem/@Key]'` could literally be `SELECT @paramKey  AS [PropertyBagItem/@Key]`. Plus you have the problem that your method of injection is a huge security risk.

Comment: @Larnu - thanks for the advice. However the number of ParamKey would vary based on the number of comma separated elements that is supplied to the SQL. If there is paramKey1, paramKey2, paramKey3 then there will be 3 nodes. May be more may be less. Same with values and datatypes.

Comment: My point stands though. `SELECT 'a,b,c'` and `SET @V =  'a,b,c'; SELECT @V` are effectively the same, and so, therefore is executing a "dynamic" statement with the definition `SET @SQL = N'SELECT ''' + @V + N''''`. There is **nothing** "dynamic" about your SQL, just a security vulnerability,

Comment: @Larnu - agree about the security risk.

Comment: Then you just need to agree on the other, as it's true. Your statement is does **not** need to be dynamic.

Comment: @Larnu - you are right - I was only focusing on the Dynamic SQL way of doing it. I would rather do it with modular functions. That should solve my problem. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Can you give us sample input data and expected output?

Comment: @Charlieface - the output would be something like - <Inputs xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><PropertyBagItem Key="NumberOfOrderToBeClosed"><Value xsi:type="xsd:int">3500</Value></PropertyBagItem><PropertyBagItem Key="OrdersOlderThan"><Value xsi:type="xsd:int">90</Value></PropertyBagItem></Inputs> - but there could multiple such sections. Depending on the comma seperated string supplied. For "Alpha,Karl,Bob" - there would 3 such sections and the name of "Key" would be Alpha, Charlie & Bob.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)